# Changing message box activation

Tags: ms-access

My database has a unique field for the name of the child receiving gifts from our Christmas project and notifies us of the duplication as we leave the record. However that is many keystrokes later. Is there a way to activate the message upon leaving the field rather than the record.?

Comment: Are you able to post the code that runs when leaving the record?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the BeforeUpdate event of the field. In this, look up the value entered and, if found, set:

```
Cancel = True
```

and pop a messagebox.